# retrieve data from two columns with the same name but different table

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to be able to select the column from users and dusers.  example:

```
select u.user, d.user FROM users u JOIN dusers .... etc.
```

...like so:

echo $row['u.user']

echo $row['d.user']

I tried this, but no go.  How do I specify what table to retrieve the user from?

Comment: Did you take a look at the structure of your array in `$row` with functions like `var_dump` or `print_r`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias the columns in the select clause:

```
select u.user AS u_user, d.user AS d_user ....
```

then you can use:

```
echo $row['u_user']  
echo $row['d_user']
```

Comment: HAH! I had tried that earlier... but the field I tried it on happened to have no data in it so I thought it didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    u.user AS u_user,
    d.user AS d_user
FROM users u JOIN dusers
```

Then:

```
echo $row['u_user'];
echo $row['d_user'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the "AS" sql attribute.

```
select u.user AS uuser, d.user AS duser FROM users u JOIN dusers ...
```

And the array will be the following :

```
echo $row['uuser']
echo $row['duser']
```